# Trying to incorporate simple slider menu using add and removeClass function with no luck

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have attempted several methods of getting my slider menu to work using jQuery and at best could only get it to function once, and then I would have to refresh the page in order for it to work again. Now I've managed to outdo myself and it has ceased to work at all. I am sharing my code in the hopes that someone might notice a glaring error - the script is a simple add/removeClass function. I originally had the document ready function in my external JS file but moved it to the head, as seen here, because I clearly have no clue what I am doing. A common error message I'm getting is that $ is not defined, however, I placed a console.log in the original external menu.js file, which suggests to me that my jQuery library would be called without issue - but like I said, I have no idea what I am doing.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width+device-width, initial-scale+1">
    <!-- [if lt IE 9]>
    <script src:"//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![end if]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.jpg">
    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" );
    });

    $( window ).on( "load", function() {
        console.log( "window loaded" );
    });
    </script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script> 
    <title>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</title>
</head>

<body> 
    <header><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp"><img src="img/header-banner.gif"></a></header>

    <i class="far fa-circle toggle_menu"></i>

    <div class="sidebar_menu">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li class="navigation_item"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp">news</a></li>
            <li class="navigation_item"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp">text</a></li>
            <li class="navigation_item"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp">exhibition</a></li>
            <li class="navigation_item"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp">about</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>`
```

main.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli');

html, body {font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
}

header {width: 970px;
    height: 90px;
}


.toggle_menu {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 15px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #648B79;
    z-index: 1000000;
    font-size: 2em;
    opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar_menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9);
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    text-align: left;  
}

.fa-times {
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-times:hover {opacity: 1;
}

.navigation {
    font-family: 'Muli';
    font-size: 1.5em;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation_item {
    margin: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.show_menu {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.opacity_zero {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#main {
    background-color: aqua;
    font-family: 'Muli', 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 201px;   
}

#slide-show {font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
            padding: 15px;
}  



#footer{font-family: 'Muli';
    background-color: aqua;
    border: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;

}

a:link {color: #555; text-decoration:none}
a:visited {color: #555; text-decoration:none}
a:hover {color:aqua; text-decoration:none; transition: 0.05s;}

/* media queries */
```

Javascipt

```
$(".toggle_menu").click(function(){
    $(".sidebar_menu").addClass("show_menu");
    $(".toggle_menu").addClass("opacity_zero");
});


$(".fa-times").click (function(){
    $(".sidebar_menu").removeClass("show_menu");
    $(".toggle_menu").removeClass("opacity_zero"); 
});
```

Comment: Please write content of your menu.js file too.

Comment: The content of the menu.js file is code at the end where I listed "Javasript"  Javascipt

Comment: $(".toggle_menu").click(function(){
        $(".sidebar_menu").addClass("show_menu");
    $(".toggle_menu").addClass("opacity_zero");
});


    $(".fa-times").click (function(){
    $(".sidebar_menu").removeClass("show_menu");
    $(".toggle_menu").removeClass("opacity_zero"); 
});

Comment: If you get the error about $ sign, Perhaps you have inserted `menu.js` before `jquery.js` in your main codes or you may be offline and have no access to CDN files.

Comment: Thank you Ali - I thought there might be an issue with the succession of scripts but I have tried a number a different configurations of the scripts

Comment: I had the script working in JS Fiddle, but it only worked once, and then I would have to do a page refresh for it to work again. No luck in CodePen and I use Brackets live feature to test from my laptop

Comment: You need to wrap your codes inside `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's **FontAwsome** causing the problem here. The latest version of this library replaces the **i** tags with **svg**, which doesn't inherit the **toggle_menu** class.
Try wrapping up the FontAwsome icon with **button** element. The code should look like this:

```
<button class="toggle_menu">
    <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation. I made the change but alas no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1- wrap your action codes inside DOM ready to make a listener on them.

2- bring your action classes out of `<i>` because the fontawsome library replaces the html tags with relevant svg so it no more works. (thanks to [@rufus1530](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353480/trying-to-incorporate-simple-slider-menu-using-add-and-removeclass-function-with/#49353859))

3- If you get errors about $ sign perhaps you have inserted your codes before jquery library or your tests are offline and you have no access to CDN files. Try replacing jquery with an offline version and check again.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".toggle_menu").click(function(){
     $(".sidebar_menu").addClass("show_menu");
        $(".toggle_menu").addClass("opacity_zero");
    });
    
         
    $(".fa-times").click (function(){
        $(".sidebar_menu").removeClass("show_menu");
        $(".toggle_menu").removeClass("opacity_zero"); 
    });
 })
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli');
    
    html, body {font-size: 12px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
    }
    
    header {width: 970px;
        height: 90px;
    }
    
    
    .toggle_menu {
        position: fixed;
        padding: 15px 20px 15px 15px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        color: black;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #648B79;
        z-index: 1000000;
        font-size: 2em;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .sidebar_menu {
        position: fixed;
        width: 200px;
        margin-left: -100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9);
        opacity: 0.9;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        text-align: left;  
    }
    
    .fa-times {
        right: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        opacity: 0.4;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .fa-times:hover {opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .navigation {
        font-family: 'Muli';
        font-size: 1.5em;
        list-style-type: none;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .navigation_item {
        margin: 10px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .show_menu {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    
    .opacity_zero {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #main {
        background-color: aqua;
        font-family: 'Muli', 'sans-serif';
        font-size: 1em;
        width: 900px;
        height: 900px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 201px;   
    }
    
    #slide-show {font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
                padding: 15px;
    }  
    
               
    
    #footer{font-family: 'Muli';
        background-color: aqua;
        border: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    
    }
    
    a:link {color: #555; text-decoration:none}
    a:visited {color: #555; text-decoration:none}
    a:hover {color:aqua; text-decoration:none; transition: 0.05s;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

    <a class="toggle_menu">
        <i class="far fa-circle "></i>
     </a>
        
        <div class="sidebar_menu">
           <a class="fa-times"> <i class="fas"></i></a>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li class="navigation_item"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp">news</a></li>
                <li class="navigation_item"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp">text</a></li>
                <li class="navigation_item"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp">exhibition</a></li>
                <li class="navigation_item"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp">about</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>`
```

Comment: Thank you Ali. In my first attempts, my script's src was set to an uncompressed jQuery library in my website's file directory. I also moved the event listener to the head when wrapping the add/removeClass functions themselves did not work originally. I wasn't aware about the font awesome class inheritance issue so thanks for that.

Comment: Another strange this is that when I wrap my Class function with the document.ready function DevTools gives me back an "Unexpected Syntax" error on the first line

Comment: Actually - I was wrong - wrapping the scripts in the Body did work but I still have the issue of it only firing once. But still better than where I was - thank you thank you!

Comment: The problem is now resolved thank you Ali Sheikhpour and rufus1530 for your help!

Comment: Thanks. If this answer was helpful you can vote up or accept it.